# Apache Tomcat cannot find external css stylesheet

Tags: html, css, jsp, tomcat, servlets

When using Apache Tomcat, It will not serve me my external CSS stylesheet called `CSS.css`. Here is a picture of its location:

[image: It is in the webapp folder]

When I try to access it from `home.jsp` using this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/CSS.css" type="text/css" >
```

nothing happens.

Also if I go to my browser and type in `localhost:8080/myappname/CSS.css`, It still doesn't find it.

I have researched this for a while and I seem to have done everything right. If anyone has an idea on why this isn't working for me that'd be great!

Comment: It seems you're running Tomcat in Eclipse - did you (re)publish your webapp after adding the CSS file?

Comment: There is no problem. Clean your app and deploy again. Ctrl+F5 in your browser.

Comment: I did those and it still wouldn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. All I had to do was add this to web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And I put all my CSS files in a folder in web app called css

Note that all CSS (and all javascript) files must be outside the WEB-INF folder. They have to be in a directly  that can be accessed publicly .

Answer (score 0):

Try by renaming the file `CSS.css` to `CSS1.css` and re-deploy the application.
If it worked then rename `CSS1.css` back to `CSS.css`