# Tomcat cannot find the CSS file

Tags: html, css, tomcat

I am working on a app development, and wanted to test the Tomcat that I just installed. I thought the default path of href in a link tag is the static folder under resources. But somehow the index.jsp cannot recognize the static folder. Is there anything wrong with my code? It cannot recognize the css file based on the code below, unless I put the CSS folder in the same directory. you can see my directories in the screenshot[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gekz3.png)]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsK4c.png)

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
Welcome
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work either if I change the url to ../../resources/static/css/style.css

The error from console is also attached.

Huge thanks!!!!

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/40695328/12709358

Comment: Where exactly did you put the files? Your screenshot does not show directories, it only shows the error message in your browser.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I put two screenshots as images in the question description. I have separated them,

Answer (score 0):

did you try absolute path "/resources/static/css/style.css" ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried this path as well... It sill not work....

Comment: what is the path of your app in browser? And what is the path to css?